# how to call a javascript funcion and get the return in C# asp .net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm trying to call a javascript funcion that returns a string value in my C# function.
[ReturnValue()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjsEK.png)

The problem is that i found some ways (CSM.RegisterClientScriptBlock for example) to call a javascript funcion, but they dont get the return of the function.

- I'm not using Razor.
- Visual Studio Version: 2012.
- I'm using .NET Framework 4.5.

  ```
  if ($.retorno() == "Não")
    return;

  if ($.retorno() != "Sim")
  {
    // Monta mensagem de confirmação para inclusão de Material com mesmo código de barras
    var mensagem = new StringBuilder();

    // Título e Mensagem
    mensagem.Append("BootstrapDialog.show({closable: false,");
    mensagem.Append("type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING,");
    mensagem.Append("title: 'Material',");
    mensagem.Append("message: 'Existem ordens separadas para este material.");
    mensagem.Append("<br><br>Deseja prosseguir com a gravação?',");

    // Botão Sim
    mensagem.Append("buttons: [{id: 'btnConfirarGravacao',");
    mensagem.Append("icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign',");
    mensagem.Append("label: 'Sim',");
    mensagem.Append("action: function (dialog) {dialog.close(); ContinuaGravacao();}},");

    // Botão Não
    mensagem.Append("{id: 'btnCancelarGravacao',");
    mensagem.Append("icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle',");
    mensagem.Append("label: 'Não',");
    mensagem.Append("action: function (dialog) {dialog.close();}}]});");

    // Exibe mensagem de confirmação
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "mensagemModalSimples", "<script>" + mensagem + "</script>", false);
  }
  ```

How to get the return of function?

Comment: What do you want to return it to?  You creating the script on the server.  The javascript will run on the client computer.  Where do you expect it to return to?  Not the C# that created it -- that is on a different computer.  So where do you want it to return to?

Comment: Could you please share your `controller` code and what exactly you want to return from there. In addition, please include your full `frontend code snippet` as well so that your expectations seems more clear.

Comment: Based on the information you provided, your problem cannot be reproduced. You can add debug to test where the data goes wrong. Also, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of how you want to return.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron i dont have a controller, only the asp page with aspx.cs class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some things and it worked when i create a WebMethod to send another requisition and continue from where i called the "yes or no" confirmation.

Frontend script js code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Scripts" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            ConfigurarMaskaras();
        });

        function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
                ConfigurarMaskaras();
            }
        }

        function ConfigurarMaskaras() {
            $("#MainContent_txtQtdSeparar").mask("###.###.##0,000000", { reverse: true });
            $("#MainContent_txtQtdSeparada").mask("###.###.##0,000000", { reverse: true });
            $("#MainContent_txtSaldoLote").mask("###.###.##0,000000", { reverse: true });
            $("#MainContent_txtSaldoEndereco").mask("###.###.##0,000000", { reverse: true });
        }

        <%-- Popup Modal Filtro do Relatório --%>
        function ExibeModalPopUpFiltro() {
            $("#ModalPopupFiltro").modal("show");
        }

        function LimparModalPopUpFiltro() {
            $("#MainContent_lblRetornoCodMaterial").text("");
            $("#MainContent_lblRetornoReferencia").text("");
            $("#MainContent_lblRetornoCodMaterial").hide();
            $("#MainContent_lblRetornoReferencia").hide();

            $(".modal-body").find("input:text, input:password, input:file, textarea").each(function () {
                $(this).val("");
            });

            $(".modal-body").find("select").each(function () {
                $("#" + $(this).attr("id")).prop("selectedIndex", 0);
            });

            $(".rtsLI")[0].click();
        }

        function ContinuarCommandItem() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Base.CadastroMaterial.aspx/GravarCommandItem",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) { MensagemRetorno(response.d); },
                failure: function (response) { MensagemRetorno(response.d); }
            });
        }

        function MensagemRetorno(retorno) {
            BootstrapDialog.show({
                closable: false,
                type: (retorno == "" ? BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS : BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER),
                title: "Material",
                message: (retorno == "" ? "Cadastro efetuado com sucesso." : retorno),
                onshown: function () { $("#btnOK").focus(); },
                buttons: [{
                    id: "btnOK",
                    icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign",
                    label: "OK",
                    action: function (dialog) {
                        dialog.close();
                        if (retorno == "") {
                            window.location.replace("Base.ListaMaterial.aspx");
                        }
                    }
                }]
            });
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

How i call it:

```
if (!granel && txtQtdMovimentar.Text.ToDecimal() > 0)
                        {
                            var quantidade = lBlItemOrdemSeparacao.QuantidadeItensSeparados(conexao, txtCodMaterialComp.Text, lDtrSeparacao["IdControleLoteEntrada"].ToInt32(),
                                lDtrSeparacao["IdControleEstoqueEnderecoEntrada"].ToInt32(), lDtrSeparacao["IdItemOrdemSeparacao"].ToInt32(), lDttEnderecoEstoque.Rows[0]["IdEnderecoEstoque"].ToInt32());

                            if (quantidade > 0)
                            {
                                if ("" == "Não")
                                    return;

                                if ("" != "Sim")
                                {
                                    // Monta mensagem de confirmação para inclusão de Material com mesmo código de barras
                                    var mensagem = new StringBuilder();

                                    // Título e Mensagem
                                    mensagem.Append("BootstrapDialog.show({closable: false,");
                                    mensagem.Append("type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING,");
                                    mensagem.Append("title: 'Material',");
                                    mensagem.Append("message: 'Existem ordens separadas para este material.");
                                    mensagem.Append("<br><br>Deseja prosseguir com a gravação?',");

                                    // Botão Sim
                                    mensagem.Append("buttons: [{id: 'btnConfirarGravacao',");
                                    mensagem.Append("icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign',");
                                    mensagem.Append("label: 'Sim',");
                                    mensagem.Append("action: function (dialog) {dialog.close(); ContinuaGravacao();}},");

                                    // Botão Não
                                    mensagem.Append("{id: 'btnCancelarGravacao',");
                                    mensagem.Append("icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle',");
                                    mensagem.Append("label: 'Não',");
                                    mensagem.Append("action: function (dialog) {dialog.close();}}]});");

                                    // Exibe mensagem de confirmação
                                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "mensagemModalSimples", "<script>" + mensagem + "</script>", false);
                                }

                                var itens = lBlItemOrdemSeparacao.ItensSeparados(conexao, txtCodMaterialComp.Text, lDtrSeparacao["IdControleLoteEntrada"].ToInt32(),
                                    lDtrSeparacao["IdControleEstoqueEnderecoEntrada"].ToInt32(), Session["IdOrdemFabricacao"].ToInt32(), lDttEnderecoEstoque.Rows[0]["IdEnderecoEstoque"].ToInt32());

                                foreach (DataRow item in itens.Rows)
                                {
                                    EstornarOrdemSeparacao(conexao, item["idItemOrdemSeparacao"].ToInt32());
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

WebMethod with code to continue the flow of logic:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static void GravarCommandItem()
        {
            var lBlDescrMat = new blMaterial();
            var lBlCle = new blControleLoteEntrada();
            var lBlCeee = new blControleEstoqueEnderecoEntrada();
            var lBlItemOrdemSeparacao = new blItemOrdemSeparacao();

            DataTable lDttSeparacao = new DataTable();
            DataRow lDtrSeparacao;

            var lBlLote = new blControleLoteEntrada();
            var lBlEndereco = new blControleEstoqueEnderecoEntrada();

            var conexao = new ConexaoBd();
            conexao.AbreConexao();

            DataTable lDttEnderecoEstoque = new DataTable();
            switch (HttpContext.Current.Session["Operacao"].ToString())
            {
                case "I":
                    try
```